# Tellraw with combination

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

[image]
[image]

I want to make several items in a `/tellraw` line, where each item can be on or off, where on items and off items can have different colors and `hoverEvent`s (maybe and `clickEvent`s). If there are too many items, and each possible combination cost a `tellraw` command, it explodes. Is there a good way to do such thing?

The selector way doesn't match `hoverEvent` requirement. Issue https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-55493 . Another solution blocked https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-129718

Comment: If you already know the bug report, why ask for help here? We can't fix the bug (except for modding), only Mojang can. Also, I don't understand this sentence: "If there are too many items, and each possible combination cost a tellraw command, it explodes." Can you explain what you mean with that, please?

Comment: @FabianRöling We can't fix the feature, but we may be able to bypass; If there are 16 items, each can be on or off, there are 65536 combinations, which seems too large to handle

Comment: Ah, so you don't want one command for 0000, one for 0001, one for 0010, one for 0011, one for 0100, etc., but instead two for the first digit, two for the second, etc.?

Comment: Are texture packs an option? You might be able to abuse translations to generate a (potentially empty) list of entity names, which are translated to only one letter.

Comment: Ah, forget it, it's possible without!

Comment: But not with hover events etc… Are those absolutely required?

Comment: What I have so far: `/tellraw @s [{"text":"abc"},{"selector":"@e[type=sheep]"}]` This shows "abc" and then either a sheep's name (or a list of sheep names) or nothing, this could be used to show either a green A or nothing and a red A or nothing, then a green B or nothing etc. But it doesn't allow for custom hover events. It does allow bold text etc., but I'm not sure if that's enough for your usecase.

Comment: Ooohh, now I also understand how your bug link is relevant! I completely missed that when jumping right into the challenge. Well, that's a bummer. It might still be possible to do something, but probably not with selectors. Maybe my first idea of using empty translations could be applied, but I currently don't have an idea how to toggle that on or off.

Comment: Also, I meant "resource packs" when I wrote "texture packs".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

team prefix&suffix can contain events, so such code makes an armor_stand that "named" aaa and show bbb when hover:

```
team add test
team modify test prefix {"text":"aaa","hoverEvent":{"action":"show_text","value":"bbb"}}
summon minecraft:armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"\"\""}
team join test @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand]
say @e[type=armor_stand]
```

Answer (score -1):

I found an easy way around this - sort of.

I don't know your situation very well, so edit it to your liking. This method hasn't really been tested - I've tested half of it but the other half is new.

First, summon four armor stands name A B C and D. Add four more armor stands named "You have reached this objective". Tag one with tag A, one with tag B, one with tag C and the last with tag D (/tag `@e[type=armor_stand,limit=1,sort=nearest]` add A). Then create two teams, one named red and one named green. Edit the team colors to red and green, respectively. Following me so far?

Next step: run these eight commands in a repeating command block:

`/execute as @e[type=armor_stand,name=A,team=red] run team join red @e[tag=A,type=armor_stand]
/execute as @e[type=armor_stand,name=A,team=green] run team join green @e[tag=A,type=armor_stand]
/execute as @e[type=armor_stand,name=B,team=red] run team join red @e[tag=A,type=armor_stand]
/execute as @e[type=armor_stand,name=B,team=green] run team join green @e[tag=A,type=armor_stand]
/execute as @e[type=armor_stand,name=C,team=red] run team join red @e[tag=A,type=armor_stand]
/execute as @e[type=armor_stand,name=C,team=green] run team join green @e[tag=A,type=armor_stand]
/execute as @e[type=armor_stand,name=D,team=red] run team join red @e[tag=A,type=armor_stand]
/execute as @e[type=armor_stand,name=D,team=green] run team join green @e[tag=A,type=armor_stand]`

Now join armor stands A B C and D to teams.

Now use this command:

`/tellraw @a {"text":"","extra":[{"selector":"@e[type=armor_stand,name=A,limit=1]","hoverEvent":{"action":"show_entity","value":"@e[tag=A]"}},{"selector":"@e[type=armor_stand,name=B,limit=1]","hoverEvent":{"action":"show_entity","value":"@e[tag=B]"}},{"selector":"@e[type=armor_stand,name=C,limit=1]","hoverEvent":{"action":"show_entity","value":"@e[tag=C]"}},{"selector":"@e[type=armor_stand,name=D,limit=1]","hoverEvent":{"action":"show_entity","value":"@e[tag=D]"}}]}`

If this works, it will show you exactly what is shown in the screenshot. All you have to do for a change is change an objective's (armor stand's) team from red to green, or vice versa, then run the command again. Does this help at all?

Comment: No. Selector in hoverEvent doesn't work

Comment: Darn. Give me one second.

Comment: Hmmm. Gamepedia doesn't have any solutions. It tells you show_entity exists but doesn't really tell you how to use it. I've tried a few experiments but got nothing. Maybe someone should ask a question about it?
Sorry I can't help with that. I don't actually use hoverEvent all that often, so I don't have a clue.

Comment: Update: Apprarently the show_entity value doesn't show the name of the entity, only the information of the entity, so it wouldn't work anyway. However, I see you've accepted the first answer, so do you not need to know anymore?

Comment: It works fine, and usually possible

Comment: Although if color, hoverevent and text are independent it may need n^3 code, it's acceptable unlike 2^n